# glossary problem

Tags: glossaries, indexing

I have the following code that works fine:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,twoside=true,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm, tmargin=2.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm, bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[nonumberlist, toc]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{smr}{name=SMR, description={Steam methane reforming}}
\newglossaryentry{x}{name=x, description={Percentage of Cerium in $ Ce_{x}Zr_{1-x}O_{2} $}}
\newglossaryentry{op}{name={OP},description={Oh Porra!}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage %for openright
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage %for openright
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables


\cleardoublepage
\printglossaries

\chapter{Introduction}
\label{chapter:Introduction}

\section{Motivation}
\label{section:motivation}
%Relevance of the subject...

The production of hydrogen has been growing and one of the reasons is the fact that hydrogen has a key role in the future production of sustainable energy, fuel cells which eliminate toxic emissions and have higher efficiency than internal combustion engines for converting chemical energy of the fuel to electrical energy. Although, it's important to mention that the bigger source for the production of hydrogen is fossil fuels. The most used method is the steam methane reforming (SMR), that uses methane ($ \mathrm{CH_{4}} $) which comes from natural gas.

\end{document}
```

Then I do makeindex and appears:

> This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit] (kpathsea + Thai
>   support). Scanning style file
>   ./Teste.ist.............................done (29 attributes redefined,
>   0 ignored). Scanning input file Teste.glo...done (0 entries accepted,
>   0 rejected). Nothing written in Teste.gls. Transcript written in
>   Teste.ilg.

After this I run my file but the glossary still doesn't appear and I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You don't use a `\gls{op}` command to add the description or a `\glsaddall` (to add them all at once without displaying it inline)

Comment: Please consider the usage of `mhchem` package for a better display of chemical formulae.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Even if I use `\glsaddall`, it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you run the `makeglossaries` script instead of `makeindex`?

Answer (score 2):

Without using a `\gls{...}` for a specific entry that should displayed in place or `\glsaddall` (for invisible adding) at all the glossary will be empty.

Make sure to run the `makeglossaries` script after compilation and recompile (twice, at best) after the script!

Unrelated: I used `mhchem` package and the `\ce` command to provide a better support for displaying chemical formulas.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,twoside=true,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm, tmargin=2.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm, bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[nonumberlist, toc]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{smr}{name=SMR, description={Steam methane reforming}}
\newglossaryentry{x}{name=x, description={Percentage of Cerium in \ce{Ce_{x}Zr_{1-x}O2}}}
\newglossaryentry{op}{name={OP},description={Oh Porra!}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\glsaddall

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage %for openright
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage %for openright
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables


\cleardoublepage
\printglossaries

\chapter{Introduction}
\label{chapter:Introduction}

\section{Motivation}
\label{section:motivation}
%Relevance of the subject...

The production of hydrogen has been growing and one of the reasons is the fact that hydrogen has a key role in the future production of sustainable energy, fuel cells which eliminate toxic emissions and have higher efficiency than internal combustion engines for converting chemical energy of the fuel to electrical energy. Although, it's important to mention that the bigger source for the production of hydrogen is fossil fuels. The most used method is the steam methane reforming (SMR), that uses methane (\ce{CH4}) which comes from natural gas.

\end{document}
```

[image]